# users_path(user) returns /users.id instead of /users/id when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I find that when I use `users_path(user)` it returns `/users.id` where id is the id of the user but I want it to return `/users/id`. My config routes.rb looks like the following.

```
# config/routes.rb
Test::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "static_pages#home"
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]

  devise_for :users
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for a path to a singular user:

```
user_path(user)
```

Use this for a path to all the users, or the index page:

```
users_path # no arguments
```