# What is the difference between the following methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`users_path` and `user_path(user1)`
I guess former goes to index action and the later to the show action of specific user

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: please refer to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300865/users-pathuser-returns-users-id-instead-of-users-id-when-using-devise

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is right:

`users_path`gives the path to the controller action `users#index` while

`user_path(user1)`gives the path to controller action `users#show` with `params[:id]` set to `user1.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
users_path returns /users
new_user_path returns /users/new
edit_user_path(:id) returns /users/:id/edit (for instance, edit_user_path(10) returns /users/10/edit)
user_path(:id) returns /users/:id (for instance, user_path(10) returns /users/10)
```

For more details
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 0):

```
users_path will routes to users#index as you expected
```

And

```
user_path(user) will redirect to users#show if method is get
```

or

```
It will redirect or routes to users#destroy if method is delete
```